# MS SQL server 2019 connection to Python, broken after clone to new computer - Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script

Tags: python, sql-server

My SQL 2019 database queries from within SSMS started throwing errors re communicating with the python runtime, immediately after cloning the operating system solid state drive to a new SSD and installing it into a new computer.

This occurs when trying to run an external python script with

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
```

The error is:

> Msg 39012, Level 16, State 14, Line 2 Unable to communicate with the
> runtime for 'Python' script for request id:
> F3A80B16-DEDC-401B-B16A-0D9D8E163CCC. Please check the requirements of
> 'Python' runtime.

I cloned the computer using Acronis True Image, and the clone completed successfully, with no reported bad sectors or any other errors.
I am running Windows 10 Home edition 22H2 with all window updates installed.
I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition 15.0.2101.7, and using SSMS version 18.8. Running Python 3.7.1.
I am running the queries on the actual server itself.

Immediately after cloning, the drive booted successfully on the new computer.
I ran Windows update to install any new drivers, and the drivers were the only new updates, as I had previously installed all available updates on the old drive.

I then tested my SQL server database, which is when I discovered this error.

I checked that enable external scripts was enabled, which it is.

I ran some basic code to test the functionality of Python within SQL, and it came up with the same error.
That code was:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import sys
'
```

I have tried to re clone the system again, with the same results.

I have ran the python version that SQL server 2019 installed at the following location manually, and it runs normally:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL15.servername\PYTHON_SERVICES

I checked the system event logs and there is a python error:

> Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.7.1150.1013, time stamp: 0x5c0f4332
> Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000000000
> Faulting process id: 0x45ac
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d9bc2d2ecbebd4
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.servername\PYTHON_SERVICES\python.exe
> Faulting module path: unknown
> Report Id: ec2f200f-47ac-433b-83f0-0d1b8bc16033
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

After reading numerous articles, I've tried enabling Named Pipes from within the
SQL Server Configuration Manager, with no change.

I've tried granting full access to the MSSQLLauchpad$*Servername* account on the Python Services folder located in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.servername" and restarting the server, without success.

I have tested the R runtime with a basic "hello world" script, and that runs successfully.

One article suggested reinstalling Numpy, which I did as well, on the python instance.

Another article suggested loading BIOS defaults, which I did, without any change.

I also added the scripts folder path, located in the folder above, to the system PATH.

I have edited the pythonlauncher.config file to change the working directory to:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.servername\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData

I have upgraded server 2019 to 2022.

I have upgraded SSMS from 18.8 to 19.x.

I have re-cloned twice.

I have also gone back to the original drive, on the original computer, and confirmed that I am not getting that error at all, either with my code, or the test code.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, just for an update... it appears to have been caused by the memory.
After re-imaging the hard disk twice, and various other attempted fixes I've listed above, I tried with some different memory.
I then ran a basic "Hello World" python script within SSMS, and it worked!
I then ran my code that calls python repeatedly, and it completed with no errors!
I've very happy, although I don't understand how the issue was caused.
I had ran Memtest86 on the original RAM overnight, and it did not fail.